# MPAndroidChart OnClickListener is not working for PieChart

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I use [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart) in my project.
Where there are four graphs,displays some information.
I want to show some detailed information to user when he clicks on specific chart.
For that I have used `view.setOnClickListener();`
but it is not working.
Is there any other method to listen click events from chart.
I found `onValueSelected();` method in MPChart documentation but it is not useful for me,because I want id of chart which is clicked.

I have used following

```
chart = (PieChart) findViewById(R.id.chart);
chart.setOnClickListener(MainActivity.this);
chart.setTouchEnabled(true);

 public void onClick(View v) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Clicked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 }
```

Also other way is

```
    chart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
          Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Clicked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       }
    });
```

But no luck.

Comment: can you post your code here ?

Comment: `chart.setHighlightPerTapEnabled(true;)` The event won't fire in case this is false.

Answer (score 4):

I have tried with onClickListener but it's not working so use following code which comes with library itself.

```
mChart.setOnChartGestureListener(new OnChartGestureListener() {

            @Override
            public void onChartTranslate(MotionEvent me, float dX, float dY) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onChartSingleTapped(MotionEvent me) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub


            }

            @Override
            public void onChartScale(MotionEvent me, float scaleX, float scaleY) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onChartLongPressed(MotionEvent me) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onChartFling(MotionEvent me1, MotionEvent me2,
                    float velocityX, float velocityY) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onChartDoubleTapped(MotionEvent me) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
```

Comment: Amol,I tried with this code,its working.But in my app there are four charts ,So i dont want to set this methods for each chart.I am looking for a code like    chart1.setOnClickListener(this);      chart2.setOnClickListener(this);  and then  public void onClick(View view){           int clicked_chart =  view.getId()    }  so i will get id of chart which is clicked

Answer (score 4):

You need to  enable

```
chart.setHighlightPerTapEnabled(true);
```

Comment: That only works with the latest version of the library as of 2.1.x it wasn't implemented yet.

Answer (score 0):

This is working in my chart

```
    chart.setClickable(true);
    chart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d("TAG", "TOUCHED IN : " + v.getId());
        }
    });
```

Comment: not working...even i enable setclickable. In my case it is showing only animation when i tap on chart.

Answer (score 0):

Also possible, use the `OnChartGestureListener` that comes with the library: [OnChartGestureListener](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/Interaction-with-the-Chart).

It distributes callbacks for all kinds of gestures (including taps / clicks).

Comment: yes Philipp,As you said OnChartGestureListener is working.But how could i get id of chart which is clicked or tapped? Beacause none of the methods contain parameter view.

Answer (score 0):

try implements your class with OnChartValueSelectedListener

```
public class MyChart implements OnChartValueSelectedListener {
...
}
```

then add the method

```
@Override
public void onValueSelected(Entry e, int dataSetIndex, Highlight h) {
//doing something when clicked
}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected() {
//doing something when nothing
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The pie chart has a onFocus listener which grabs the event before it can get to your onClick handler. Do the following for each of your pie charts.

```
// Disable touch listener so we can get onClick events.
pieChart.setOnTouchListener(null);
// Make sure it's clickable.
pieChart.setClickable(true);
```

By doing this, you wouldn't be able to take advantage of any of the onTouch functionality but it doesn't sound like you want that.

Comment: If you set pieChart's `OnTouchListener(null)`, you can not click any part of chart. Wrong answer. [Source](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/Interaction-with-the-Chart)